# Criar pasta a partir de um arquivo em excel em python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, arquivo, biblioteca, diretório

Criei um programa para criar pasta a partir de entrada de usuários, mas quero saber se tem como criar um programa pra ler um arquivo em excel e a partir dessas informações criar várias pastas para o caso de um número de pastas muito grande.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os.path
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
import fsspec

def restart_program():
    pass

diretório = '/'
EPS_UTD = input("Para x digite 1, para y digite 2: ")

if EPS_UTD == "1":
    QTD = input("Para quantas EPS deseja criar pastas?: ")
    if QTD == "1":
        EPS = input("Digite o nome da EPS: ")
        CONTRATO = input("Digite o número do contrato: ")
        ANO = input("Digite o ANO do projeto com 4 dígitos: ")
        PROJETO = input("Digite o número do projeto: ")
        if not os.path.exists(diretório+EPS.upper()+'/'+PROJETO+'_'+ANO+'/A'+ANO+PROJETO):
            os.makedirs(diretório+EPS.upper()+'/'+PROJETO+'_'+ANO+'/A'+ANO+PROJETO)
    if QTD == "2":
        (e assim por diante...)
    print("Pasta criada")
else:
    print("Entrada inválida")
    restart_program()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar um ficheiro xlsx com este formato. Carregar o workbook, obter o nº de filas, e criar um ciclo para ler cada fila e criar a pasta.

| Nome EPS | Nº Contrato | Ano | Nº Projeto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Eps1 | 1 | 2000 | 1 |
| Eps2 | 1 | 2001 | 2 |
| Eps3 | 2 | 2002 | 3 |

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl

ficheiro_excel = 'Book1.xlsx'
diretório = './'

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(ficheiro_excel)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
qtd = sheet_obj.max_row

for i in range(2, qtd + 1):
    EPS = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
    n_contrato = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 2).value
    ANO = str(sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 3).value)
    PROJETO = str(sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 4).value)

    if not os.path.exists(diretório+EPS.upper()+'/'+PROJETO+'_'+ANO+'/A'+ANO+PROJETO):
        os.makedirs(diretório+EPS.upper()+'/'+str(PROJETO)+'_'+ANO+'/A'+ANO+PROJETO)
```